# React Native Local Authentication Refresh Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm trying to develop local authentication for my application that I wrote in react native, using the phone's biometric data and, if necessary, the phone password. The codes I wrote for local authentication work correctly and when the app is reloaded, it enters the local authentication screen and asks for face id or fingerprint. There is no problem until here. However, when I set the minutes for the password request part (by checking the app state, I give the condition and keep the time the application is running in the background and the instant app state), I cannot bring up the local authentication screen according to the condition in the main navigator. I'm leaving the codes below please help!

```
import { SET_SCREEN_LOCK,SET_SCREEN_LOCK_RANGE,HANDLE_APP_STATE_CHANGE } from "./actions"; //redux reducer where I keep local authentication data

const INITIAL_STATE={
  screenLock:"none",
  screenLockRange:"0",
  currentAppState:"",
}

export function screenLockReducer(state=INITIAL_STATE,action){
  switch (action.type){
    case 'SET_SCREEN_LOCK':
      return{...state,screenLock: action.payload,screenLockRange: state.screenLockRange}
    case 'SET_SCREEN_LOCK_RANGE':
      return {...state,screenLockRange: action.payload,screenLock: state.screenLock}
    case 'HANDLE_APP_STATE_CHANGE':
      return {...state,currentAppState: action.payload,screenLockRange: state.screenLockRange,screenLock: state.screenLock}
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const appState = React.useRef(AppState.currentState); //I check app state in app.js
useEffect(() => {
    //I update time and app state according to app state change
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', nextAppState => {
      if (
        nextAppState==='inactive'||nextAppState==='background'
      ) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('@currentTime', moment().format('HH:mm')).then(r => {
          AsyncStorage.getItem('@currentTime').then(time=>{
            console.log("appjs",time);
            store.dispatch(handleAppStateChange(nextAppState));
            AsyncStorage.setItem('@appState',nextAppState).then(r=>{});
          })
        });
        console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
      }else{
        store.dispatch(handleAppStateChange(nextAppState));
      }
      appState.current = nextAppState;
      console.log('AppState', appState.current);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, [appState.current]);

//the main navigator that I'm trying to bring up the local authentication screen
const {screenLock}=useSelector(state=>state.screenLockState);
  const {screenLockRange}=useSelector(state=>state.screenLockRangeState);
  const {currentAppState}=useSelector(state=>state.currentAppStateState);

useEffect(()=>{
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@currentTime').then(value => {
      if(value!==null){
        let time=moment(value,'HH:mm').add(screenLockRange,'minutes');
        setInactiveTime(moment(value,'HH:mm').add(screenLockRange,'minutes'));
        console.log("currentTime",value);
        console.log("added time",time);
      }
    });
  },[currentAppState]);

return(
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, animationTypeForReplace: 'push', animation:'fade',gestureEnabled:false }}>
              {screenLock==='lock'&&moment.utc(moment(time,"HH:mm").diff(moment(inactiveTime,"HH:mm"))).format('HH:mm')>"00:00"?(
                <>
                  <Stack.Screen name={'LocalAuthenticationScreen'} component={LocalAuthenticationScreen}/>
                </>
                ):<></>
              }
              <Stack.Screen name={'DrawerNavigator'} component={DrawerNavigator}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        )
```